# JQuery base64 function implementation

Tags: jquery, events, base64

I can't figure out why is not working a jquery plugin (base64 encode decode) inside an event function.

This way works:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){  
    data = $.base64Encode('something');  
    alert(data);  
  });
```

But when trying to add in an event function, I get the **$.base64Encode is not a function** error

```
  $(document).ready(function(){  
    $('#submit').click(function(e){
      data = $.base64Encode('something');  
      alert(data); 
      e.preventDefault();
     }); 
  });
```

The Jquery plugin is found at:
http://plugins.jquery.com/project/base64

Comment: Can you show the full document head? (At least everything script-related)

Comment: Is it possible you're including jQuery in the page twice?

Comment: @Nick Craver Post it as answer and will accept it. That is the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check that you're not including jQuery twice in the page.  What this does is the first one loads, the plugin defines itself on *that* `jQuery` object, and when jQuery is included a second time, the `window.jQuery`object gets overridden...and the plugin won't be on it :)

You'd see this when running it later, whereas your `document.ready` might be located before the 2nd jQuery inclusion.

Comment: Please check the other related question of my buddy too, you might know an answer for it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538849/zfdebug-jquery-interference

Answer (score 1):

Nick Craver has right! I use Zfdebug for Zend framework and that already includes JQUERY,
and I included twice due to ZF aut include JQUERY. Thank you

I made a new question related to how can I include only once Jquery in a Zfdebug specific environment [ZFdebug Jquery interference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538849/zfdebug-jquery-interference)

Comment: I made a change and included the plugin before the first Jquery inclusion, now it works, but when I put the application to production (This takes out the first Jquery inclusion then I can't register the plugin on that Jquery) more detailed problem on the upper link

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. You might have an unrelated Javascript error that's causing the base64 library not to load correctly.

Answer (score 0):

in the header i have

```
<html>
<head>
<title>{TITLE}</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="js/Jquery/jquery.base64.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#submit').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        data = $.base64Encode('something');
    alert(data);
    });
});

</script>
</head>
```

and a form with the submit button

```
<input id="submit" type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" class="button">
```

but as I mentioned if i put outside of click function the the `data = $.base64Encode('something');` then it works.

More complicating the thing I use Zend Framework and FastTemplate